# How to fix Firebase Storage reference error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm getting an error with firebase and my code.

> Type 'StorageReference' has no member 'put'

I tried putData and still nothing. what is the best solution to fix this problem?

I'm also getting this error when users tap to pick a profile picture

> 'UIImageJPEGRepresentation' has been replaced by instance method
>   'UIImage.jpegData(compressionQuality:)'

```
StorageReference.put(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in



if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1)
```

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theres a article how to upload data to storage on firebase:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files

```
    // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
let uploadTask = riversRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
  guard let metadata = metadata else {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    return
  }
  // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
  let size = metadata.size
  // You can also access to download URL after upload.
  riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    guard let downloadURL = url else {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      return
    }
  }
}
```